# TAG vs LAG stats in HU

Tags: statistics, heads-up

What are the typical stats for VPIP, PFR, 3bet etc. of a good TAG and a LAG in NL high-stakes heads up poker?

Comment: This question is too general, what is the structure of HU? Is it cash game? With what stacks? Is it HU SNG? Regular, Turbo, HyperTurbo? I thing there are no good TAGs on high stakes HU as playing tight in HU is not a good play.

Comment: @Tomas this is nonsense. It is obvious that a tight HU player can play way more hands than a tight fullring player and would still be considered as tight. So as in all structures and variants, you can also be successful with a tight approach

Answer (score 1):

[sharkscope.com](http://harkscope.com) lets you search for stats of some famous players, you can check it.

Dont try blindly to copy/achieve that stats, your play depends on your opponent tendencies, your goal is to have profit, therefore you have to consider your opponent tendencies to play. Heads Up especially is very "wild" and your decisions vary a lot depending on your opponent.

Also, if there is stat like "PFR = 50%", it does not mean, that the player plays the top 50% of hands. He can have like 30% from top hands and 20% hands from bottom range to balance his strong/weak ranges and confuse opponents.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at other players stats is at best a waste of time and at worst a serious departure from NLhu study.

Whether your game is tighter or looser, more or less aggressive, studying the stats of others winners is of no consequence. Your game is your game. Don't ever forget that by vainly attempting to artificially adapting your game to someone else's, it simply does not work that way. Remember too, what Phil Ivey said about practice.

"There is no substitute. "